# useEffect for real time data update

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I am creating an easy chat app, with different text channels. I am facing an infinite loop issue when using the useEffect hook to update the messagesList on real time. You can see the code below but this is what I am trying to achieve:

- First useEffect is for the chat window to scroll to the last message every time there is a change in the messagesList array. This means: I am in the middle of the messages window, I write a new message and it takes me to the bottom. This is working fine.
- Second useEffect is for the messagesList to be rendered whenever the channel is changed or there is any change in the messagesList. Adding the messagesList as a dependency is causing the infinite loop... but I think I need it cause otherwise the following happens: user1 is inside the chat channel and user2 writes a new message. User1 wont see the new message displayed as his chat is not being re-rendered. How would you make it for the new message to be displayed for user1?

Sorry for the confusing question and thanks a lot in advance!

```
    useEffect(() => {
    anchor.current.scrollIntoView(false);
  }, [messagesList]);
```

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      collection(firestore, `channels/${activChannel}/messages`),
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs);
        getMessagesList();
      }
    );
    return () => unsubscribe();
}, [activChannel, messagesList]);
```

Comment: Did you try exploring the useSyncExternalStore for the above issue as suggested by Dean? Was it helpful?

Comment: I took a look at it but was not able to implement it in my project. I did not manage to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with firestore, but perhaps you could tie the updating of the messages to the event that an user submits his message or use `useSyncExternalStore`. [This](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) piece of documentation on useEffect use cases might help you.

an excerpt from the docs:

> Here, the component subscribes to an external data store (in this
> case, the browser navigator.onLine API). Since this API does not exist
> on the server (so it can’t be used to generate the initial HTML),
> initially the state is set to true. Whenever the value of that data
> store changes in the browser, the component updates its state.
>
> Although it’s common to use Effects for this, React has a
> purpose-built Hook for subscribing to an external store that is
> preferred instead. Delete the Effect and replace it with a call to
> useSyncExternalStore:

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dean. The updating of the messages cannot be tie to the submit event cause this would only update the messages list for the user who sent that message. The other user would not see that message unless he refreshes the page of changes the channel. I will take a look at the useSyndExternalStore :)